# Javascript function overwrites the submit function

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, dom, form-submit

Good afternoon, my problem is that when using a date-picker function, referencing it with the ID of the field, the form submission button focuses on the field with the date-picker ID. This generates a loop that I have not been able to solve on my own.

[Before press submit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwEBr.png)

[When i press submit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67Y7U.png)

> Declaration of JS:

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Sistema MVC</title>
<!--Boostrap-->
<link href="~/Scripts/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!--Jquery-->
<script src="~/assets/js/jquery-3.3.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery UI CSS Reference -->
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Scripts/bootstrap4-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Required jQuery and jQuery UI Javascript references -->
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap4-toggle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
.
.
.
.
.
<!--Boostrap-->
<script src="~/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--ResponseModel-->
<script src="~/Assets/js/ini.js"></script>
<script src="~/Assets/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script src="~/Assets/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Assets/js/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

> JS function :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    // Reset language
    $.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
        closeText: 'Cerrar',
        prevText: '< Ant',
        nextText: 'Sig >',
        currentText: 'Hoy',
        monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
        dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mié', 'Juv', 'Vie', 'Sáb'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Ju', 'Vi', 'Sá'],
        weekHeader: 'Sm',
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        firstDay: 1,
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        yearSuffix: ''
    };
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["es"]);
    // This will make every element with the id "date-picker" into a DatePicker element
    $('#date-picker').datepicker();
});
</script>
```

> DOM Element

-- date-picker --

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Fecha de Creacion")
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.fechacreacion, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}",
                new { @class = "form-control" , @id = "date-picker"})
</div>
```

> -- submit button --

```
<div class="text-right">
    <button type="submit" id="otroBoton" class="btn btn-primary">Grabar</button>
    <a href="~/Control" class="btn btn-danger">Cancelar</a>
</div>
```

I await your help, thank you very much.

EDIT 1:

All form code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Guardar", "Asignacion", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frm-asignacion" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.asignacion_id)
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">Información de Asignacion</div>
        <div class="card-body">   
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-4">
                        @Html.Label("Id")
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.asignacion_id, new
                        { @class = "form-control", disabled = true })
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-4">
                        @Html.Label("Semestre")
                        <select name="semestre_id" class="form-control">
                            <option @(Model.semestre_id.Equals("") ? "Selected" : "") value="">
                                -- Seleccione --
                            </option>
                            @foreach (var s in semestre)
                            {
                            <option @(Model.semestre_id.Equals(s.semestre_id) ? "Selected" : "") value="@s.semestre_id">@s.nombre</option>
                            }
                        </select>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.semestre_id, null,
                                          new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-4">
                        @Html.Label("Fecha de Creacion")
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.fecharegistro, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new
                        { @class = "form-control", @id = "date-picker", })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-9">
                        @Html.Label("Titulo")
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.titulo, new
                        { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.titulo, null,
                                          new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-3">
                        @Html.Label("Estado")
                        <input id="estadoCheckbox" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" @(Model.estado == "A" ? "checked" : "")
                               data-on="Activo" data-off="Inactivo" data-size="normal" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-width="100%">
                        <input name="estado" id="estado" type="hidden" value="@(Model.estado == "A" ? "A" : "I")">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="text-right">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Grabar</button>
        <a href="~/Asignacion" class="btn btn-danger">Cancelar</a>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: can you show all your elements under `form` tag including itself too

Comment: @AntihypeBird It is the only one in that `div`. I have several divs with the `form` tag but they are separated.

Comment: Well i dont see a form tag or anything pointing to the click of that submit button, meaning its probably simply submitting the entire form (all divs) everytime. Its not very clear what the issue is or what your code is when truncated into snippets like that. Posting the whole thing could help us figure out what's going on and how to help you.

One thing that could help you if you can't post your code in full for any reasons; Add an onclick event to your submit button, and code a js function that calls the form submit you want (with any needed parameters)

Comment: @Spacemonkey added. When i put `submit()` function in the button, the element `date-picker` is selected again, and shows the calendar, but the form is submitted.